# How to make a break line in a tweet using the API with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm using [twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update) to POST a tweet. I want to add a break line. This is my code:

```
tweetToPublish.status = `${msg}\n\r${book}`;
twitterClient.post('statuses/update', tweetToPublish);
```

However, it only show a break line in web, but not in the mobile app. What is the best way to do it?

I have also tried with %0D%0A.

Comment: In string templates you could break the line without \n. Try to just write `${book}` for a new line

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have finally solved my problem with  \n\n. But your solution also works.